# PostgreSQL WHERE clause on ts_rank Error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to execute the following simple query:

```
SELECT "Documents", "Sentences"."sentence","Sentences"."VectorValue", 
ts_rank("Sentences"."VectorValue", plainto_tsquery('Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. ')) as sim
FROM "Documents", "Sentences"
Where sim > 0.5
And "Documents"."Id" = "Sentences"."DID"
LIMIT 10;
```

But I keep getting this ERROR: column "sim" does not exist

I tried this and it worked but doesnt look efficient, it took 5 secs to execute :

```
SELECT ...., .... , 
ts_rank("Sentences"."VectorValue", plainto_tsquery('Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. '))
FROM "Documents", "Sentences"
Where ts_rank("Sentences"."VectorValue", plainto_tsquery('Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. ')) > 0.5
And "Documents"."Id" = "Sentences"."DID"
LIMIT 10;
```

Usually, ts_rank gives results from 0-0.99 based on how relevant documents are to a specific query!

Any Ideas?

Also, Can this be improved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query:

```
select
exe.*
from
(
    SELECT "Documents", "Sentences"."sentence","Sentences"."VectorValue", 
    ts_rank("Sentences"."VectorValue", plainto_tsquery('Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. ')) as sim
    FROM "Documents", "Sentences"
    And "Documents"."Id" = "Sentences"."DID"
) exe
where sim > 0.5
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: I'm assuming you meant
    Where "Documents"."Id" = "Sentences"."DID"

It worked, Thank you!

Execute time 4.5 s

Answer (score 0):

Write your ts_rank as lateral join:

```
SELECT "Documents", "Sentences"."sentence","Sentences"."VectorValue"
FROM "Documents", "Sentences",
ts_rank("Sentences"."VectorValue", plainto_tsquery('Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. ')) as sim
Where sim > 0.5
And "Documents"."Id" = "Sentences"."DID"
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Lateral Joins looks possible, the thing is, i'm using this query in a web application. So do i really need a join? I needed the data to be displayed  in a view!

Comment: You can use your function as subquery to access the results. So you can use it in the Where or Select section. It is readible and compact. The result is same as @Abihabi87 s answer.
<Subqueries appearing in FROM can be preceded by the key word LATERAL.>
<Table functions appearing in FROM can also be preceded by the key word LATERAL, but for functions the key word is optional> For more info look at this: 
[Lateral Joins](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL)